# How to set a crontab with html request using flask-crontab?

Tags: python, html, linux, flask, cron

I'd like to run a html page where I use a button to set a specific time (see below) which later runs a cronjob via the module [flask-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/flask-crontab/). How can I use `minute`, `hour`, `day`, `month` outside `def get_time()` without setting the variables global?
Whats a solid way to use flask-crontab here?

```
APP = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(APP)
crontab = Crontab(APP)

...

@APP.route('/randompage.html' methods = ['POST', 'GET])
def get_time():
    time_req = request.args.get("html_time")
    format_time = datetime.strptime(time_req, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")

    minute = format_time.minute
    hour = format_time.hour
    day = format_time.day
    month = fomrat_time.month

    return render_template('randompage.html', time_req=time_req)


@crontab.job()
def exe_control():
    do something here
```

Button on html-page:

```
<form action="/randompage.html" method="GET">
<input type="datetime-local" name="html_time"/>
<input type="submit"/></form>
```

Comment: you would have to use global variables `minute, hour, day, month`, or write in database, and read from database in other functions. But all this can be useless if you want to use these values in `crontab.job(minute=minutes, ...)`. You would have to use `crontab.job()` 9as normal function, not decorator) directly `get_time` to add task to crontab.

Answer (score 0):

To use values `minute, hour, day, month` in other functions you have to use `global` variables or keep in global `list`/`dictionary` or save in `file`/database` and read in other functions.

But if you want these values to use as values in `@crontab.job(minute=..., hour=...)` then it is useless. You should run it directly in `get_time` as normal function

```
crontab.job(minute=minute, ...)(exe_control)
```

---

```py
APP = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(APP)
crontab = Crontab(APP)

# ...

@APP.route('/randompage.html' methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def get_time():
    time_req = request.args.get("html_time")
    format_time = datetime.strptime(time_req, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")

    minute = format_time.minute
    hour = format_time.hour
    day = format_time.day
    month = fomrat_time.month

    crontab.job(minute=minute, hour=hour, day=day, month=month)(exe_control)

    return render_template('randompage.html', time_req=time_req)

# - without decorator -
def exe_control():
    do something here
```